# Exception on DateTime Conversion

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime

I'm trying to format a list of datetime. One date is in the format same as what i provided but the factors are not in place. That line of code is given below. Can someone tell me how to skip the error for the below line?

```
Convert.ToDateTime("22-01-2013 00:00:00").ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Comment: What is the problem with this code? What "factors" are you talking about?

Comment: what exception are you getting?

Comment: Trying this, I get no errors. What error are you getting? What culture is the application running under.

Comment: Exception : "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."

Comment: And the culture? What culture are you running the application under? With `en-GB` I have no problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would avoid using `Convert.ToDateTime` to start with. I would suggest using [`DateTime.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparse.aspx) or (preferrably) [`DateTime.TryParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact.aspx). Both of these will return a value indicating whether the conversion succeeded, so you don't need to start catching exceptions in order to skip bad data. For example:

```
DateTime parsed;
if (DateTime.TryParse(text, out parsed))
{
    string reformatted = parsed.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
    // Use reformatted
}
else
{
    // Log error, perhaps?
}
```

If you have multiple possible formats, you should consider [using the overload of `TryParseExact` which allows you to specify multiple formats in a single call](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h9b85w22.aspx).

As well as the *format*, you should consider the *culture* you want to use. In the above code (and your code) it will use the executing thread's culture. Is that always what you want? The culture can affect all kinds of things - usually if you're specifying a custom format, you want to use the invariant culture. Otherwise you could end up using a non-Gregorian calendar unexpectedly, for example...

EDIT: If your input is *always* in the format `dd-MM-yyyy`, then you should probably use:

```
DateTime parsed;
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(text, "dd-MM-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                           DateTimeStyles.Default, out parsed))
{
    string reformatted = parsed.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                                         "yyyy-MM-dd");
    // Use reformatted
}
else
{
    // Log error, perhaps?
}
```

Comment: How can i bring the format 22-01-2013 to 'yyyy-MM-dd' ? I need the datetime in 'yyyy-MM-dd' only :(

Comment: @NewBie: If you know the format will always be `dd-MM-yyyy`, you should use `TryParseExact` instead of `TryParse`. Your question is very unclear in terms of your expected input.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `Convert.ToDateTime` use `DateTime.Parse` or `DateTime.ParseExact`

[`ParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx) gives you more control over the format, so for example:

```
DateTime.ParseExact("22-01-2013 00:00:00","dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

There is also a `TryParseExact` variant, which allows you to gracefully handle parse errors.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [`DateTime.ParseExact()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7ee1y0t7.aspx) method instead of.

> Converts the specified string representation of a date and time to its
>   DateTime equivalent.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{

    Console.WriteLine(DateTime.ParseExact("22-01-2013 00:00:00", "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));

}
```

Here is a [`DEMO`](http://ideone.com/eE71vO).

Also check out [`Coding Best Practices Using DateTime in the .NET Framework`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973825.aspx) which I think every .NET developer should read.

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
DateTime.ParseExact("22-01-2013 00:00:00","dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

This way you can specify the exact format for your date-string.